# Put count of rows - count({your filed}) from subreports to highest section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

is there any way to put count of rows - count({your filed}) from subreports of below details sections to first detail section, not sure if it's possible:

[image]

Comment: I did some tests right now and i could not find a way to do that (i am not saying it is not possible, but i was not able to do that). I usually would precalculate the countings and put them in the dataset instead of calculating inside crystal reports. But i understand it may not be possible in many scenarios.

Comment: I count it with count({filed}) in formula but whatever works is ok for me, just need to pass count from below subreports to detail a

Comment: You could try a shared variable.

Comment: I tested with shared variable and whileprinting but no success

Comment: Is there any way to tell crystal to run detail a at the end so it reads variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way but your may become bit slow (depends on your data...only slow if data is huge).

create one more detail section and take height of section to tthe minimum and in that section place all sub reports that you want to pass and then create the report as it is.

now you will be able to pass the data as required only change is addition of one more detail section and this will be the first section with height 0, and rest all same.